# How to add a label with `\draw` command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, draw

I have the following plot.
[image]

How can I add a label to the point in this plot?

I have already tried `\draw[fill, label=A] (-3, 3) circle [radius=1mm];`, but it didn't work.
And `\node` seems too big for my grid if I put a label inside the node.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\node[circle, draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=2pt, label=A]  at (-3, 3) {};`? For further help please provide the code for small but complete document, which reproduce showed image.

Comment: @Zarko OMG, you did me a great favor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suplement to @Andy Wang answer (+1), showing how to make code shorter by defining style of dots:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % it load tikz too
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         > = {Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
dot/.style = {circle, draw, fill=#1, inner sep=2pt}
                        ] 
\draw[help lines] (-5, -5) grid (5, 5);
% draw coordinate axes
\draw[<->, thick] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[<->, thick] (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$y$};
% dots
\node[dot=black,  label=A]  at (-3,3) {};
\node[dot=blue,   label=B]  at (-1,1) {};
\node[dot=red,    label=C]  at (2, 3) {};
\node[dot=yellow, label=D]  at (4, 1) {};
\node[dot=green,  label=E]  at (2,-3) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[help lines] (-5, -5) grid (5, 5);
      % draw coordinate axes
      \draw[<->, thick](-5.5,0)--(5.5,0)node[right]{$x$};
      \draw[<->, thick](0,-5.5)--(0,5.5)node[above]{$y$};
      \node[circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=2pt, label=A]  at (-3, 3) {};
      \node[circle, draw, fill=blue, inner sep=2pt, label=B]  at (-1, 1) {};
      \node[circle, draw, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, label=C]  at (2, 3) {};
      \node[circle, draw, fill=yellow, inner sep=2pt, label=D]  at (4, 1) {};
      \node[circle, draw, fill=green, inner sep=2pt, label=E]  at (2, -3) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for Zarko's help.